# Authenticating Google Calendar API from server to server directly using php

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Background:
Creating a project where a user can create/edit/delete a calendar events on my calendar without the need to authenticate themselves. They can add or remove users on that calendar event. I have credentials to my google account to authenticate the requests. I want to talk directly to google calendar api without the need to insert username/password (which I can provide from the backend, if required).

Technology:
PHP7.0/ SQL SERVER/ JavaScript

Issue/Requirement:
I have created the project in Google and added credentials for "service account key". I have all the required keys for creating the project. How do I talk to the google server directly without using a frontend page or console and directly go ahead with creating an event?

Answer (score 0):

- How to quickly set up a PHP project using Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
- How to authenticate with a service account using Google APIs on PHP: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts
- How to create events using the Calendar API using PHP language:  https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#metadata

Using all the examples above you should be able to easily build yourself the solution you want.

Comment: I already know the links that you mentioned here. Done with registering the project, fetching json keys and client ID. Please read the question completely. I need to communicate with the google server directly, without any user input and create a calendar event.

Comment: @RohanTapiyawala When using a service account, you don't need any interaction with the application (there is no manual OAuth authentication flow involved). You can set your PHP script as a cron task and it should run without issues/requesting anything to you. Is this what you mean? Cheers